# CodeBlock throwing IAE because CassName does not pass is TypeName check

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

I tried to initialize a property, though CodeBlock#of throws an IllegalArgumentException in CodeBlock#argToType

I looked into the root cause of the error which was at CodeBlock#argToType.
Even if `o` is a ClassName(which also is a TypeName) it does not pass the `is TypeName -> o` check and throws the IllegalArguementException.

```
val initString = "mutableMapOf(Pair(%T, %T), Pair(%T, %T))"
val initArgs = arraysOf(...)
CodeBlock.of(initString, initArgs)
```

I expected the CodeBlock to be built correctly, but instead it throws the `IllegalArguementException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced you problem and was able to fix it; I think the key question is **how you pass initArgs to CodeBlock.of**: this method is expecting a second varargs parameter but you're passing a single Array<...> value.

Changing you code as follows seems to work:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val initString = "mutableMapOf(Pair(%T, %T), Pair(%T, %T))"
    val initArgs = arrayOf(String::class.java, String::class.java, String::class.java, String::class.java)
    val result = CodeBlock.of(initString, *initArgs)
    println("result is $result")
}
```

The key point is to pass `*initArgs`, and not `initArgs`, as second parameter of `CodeBlock.of`.

I explicitly initialized `initArgs`' values witch *type* values, in order to match `%T` placeholder expectations.

I hope this can help you!

Comment: Ahh makes sense, while not completely new to kotlin I still don't know all of it of course. My thought process was that if the varargs will be treated as a array in the method, passing an already made array would be fine. Thanks for the ``*array`` tip. I'll add it when I get a chance, though I'll mark this as solved since I think this was my problem. Thanks :D